# Express post do not post data leaving req.body undefined

Tags: node.js, express

I was trying to write some test which will emulate the post, but I have realised that nothing is posting. After further debugging, I realised that req.body is always undefined. Question is where did I make a mistake and how do I fix it. I seems that the problem is somewhere in the app.js file with order how the middleware loads but I can not figure it out where.

app.js

```
'use strict';
const createError = require('http-errors');
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const logger = require('morgan');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const fs = require('fs');
const session = require('express-session');
const redis = require('redis');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const redisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);
const client = redis.createClient();

const app = express();

const _UTILS = require('./application/_UTILS');

const db = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('/srv/webkb_mean/config/configFiles/database.json', 'utf8'));

mongoose.connect('mongodb://' + db['mongodb']['url'] + '/webKB-main');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;



app.use(session({
    secret: _UTILS.getHashedValue(),
    // create new redis store.
    store: new redisStore({
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 6379,
        client: client,
        ttl: 36000
    }),
    saveUninitialized: false,
    resave: false
}));

require('./config/router')(app);

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}));

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'views')));

app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile)



// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
// app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
//     // set locals, only providing error in development
//     res.locals.message = err.message;
//     res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};
//
//     // render the error page
//     res.status(err.status || 500);
//     res.render('error');
// });
//


module.exports = app;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your adding your `bodyParser` middleware to your server after you’ve added your routes. This is because express executes middleware(which includes routers since they are also middleware) in the order which they were added via `.use()`.

Just move your router registration line:

```
require('./config/router')(app);
```

After your last middleware and before your 404 NOT FOUND handler.

```
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile)

require('./config/router')(app);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    next(createError(404));
});
```